# profiling numpy with cProfile not giving useful results

Tags: numpy, cprofile

This code:

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile

shp = (1000,1000)
a = np.ones(shp)
o = np.zeros(shp)

def main():
    np.divide(a,1,o)
    for i in xrange(20):
        np.multiply(a,2,o)
        np.add(a,1,o)

cProfile.run('main()')
```

prints only:

```
         3 function calls in 0.269 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.269    0.269 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.269    0.269    0.269    0.269 testprof.py:8(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Prof
iler' objects}
```

Can I get cProfile to work with numpy to tell me how many calls it makes to the varous `np.*` calls and how much time it spends on each?

**edit**

It is too cumbersome to wrap each of the numpy functions individually as hpaulj suggests, so I'm trying something like this to temporarily wrap many or all of the functions of interest:

```
def wrapper(f, fn):
    def ff(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    ff.__name__ = fn
    ff.func_name = fn
    return ff

for fn in 'divide add multiply'.split():
    f = getattr(np, fn)
    setattr(np, fn, wrapper(f, fn))
```

but cProfile still refers to *all* them as `ff`

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the relevant calls in Python functions?

```
def mul(*args):
    np.multiply(*args)
def add(*args):
    np.add(*args)

def main():
    np.divide(a,1,o)
    for i in xrange(20):
        mul(a,2,o)
        add(a,1,o)
```

That's basically the idea in this SO thread about improving profiling granularity - it profiles function calls, not lines.

[Does effective Cython cProfiling imply writing many sub functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005233/does-effective-cython-cprofiling-imply-writing-many-sub-functions)

Comment: points, but this would be far too cumbersome for my real-life profiling.  I've attempted some automatic wrapping, but am failing (see edit if you want) I even tried this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81535-allowing-the-python-profiler-to-profile-c-modules/ but somethings amiss there too.