# line_profiler not working as expected

Tags: python, profiling

Trying to use line_profiler as an API.  Following [their docs](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/#line-profiler) and [this tutorial](https://zapier.com/engineering/profiling-python-boss/) (scroll down to Line Profiling), I get a minimalist test case for profiling some numpy ufuncs:

```
import numpy as np
import line_profiler
import time

shp = (1000,1000)
a = np.ones(shp)
o = np.zeros(shp)

def main():
    t = time.time()
    np.divide(a,1,o)
    for i in xrange(200):
        np.multiply(a,2,o)
        np.add(a,1,o)
    print 'duration', time.time()-t

profiler = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
profiler.add_function(main)
main()
profiler.print_stats()
```

I get this in stdout which indicates that `main` ran, but was not profiled:

```
duration 2.6779999733
Timer unit: 5.59936e-07 s

File: testprof.py
Function: main at line 9
Total time: 0 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     9                                           def main():
    10                                               t = time.time()
    11                                               np.divide(a,1,o)
    12                                               for i in xrange(200):
    13                                                   np.multiply(a,2,o)
    14                                                   np.add(a,1,o)
    15                                               print 'duration', time.time
()-t
```

I'm new to line_profiler.  See my [other q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434042/profiling-numpy-with-cprofile-not-giving-useful-results) if curious why I don't use cProfile.

Comment: I found a workaround, but would still like to know if anyone can or cannot replicate this to see if it is a problem with my setup.  Workaround: use `profiler.run('main()')` instead of `main()`

Comment: `profiler.run('main()')` - It also works for me. Thanks!

Comment: profiler.run('function()') where function() is the function I want to profile was the solution for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Try add

> profiler.enable_by_count()

before

> main()